# My routes return errors in Laravel, Apache

Tags: php, laravel, apache, manjaro

Whenever I try to use a route I get "object not found" and "error 404".  I am running my server on Manjaro/Arch (locally anyway). Also, this is my first time using Laravel.

I am using Apache for my server. It is running as I can load the Laravel page from 127.0.0.1/path/to/public/. I have been using this same server for other projects and have had no issues.

I even tried changing the document root to the actual root, i.e., I can now just run using 127.0.0.1

I have changed Allow override to All in my httpd.conf  which seems to solve this issue for 99% of people. I made sure I restarted the server after .conf edits.

my web.php: (that first route is the only code I have written for this project)

```
Route::get('/hello',function(){
    return 'Hello World';
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

output from command `php artisan route:list`

```
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | hello    |      | Closure | web          |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
```

From what other solutions to this question I have seen suggest that my .htaccess is correct:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This, not a Laravel issue I think as if I run `php artisan serve` I can use the route finding, i.e., 127.0.0.1:8000/hello will print hello world in my browser.

Comment: And what do you get when you use Php artisan server?

Comment: Oh ok, what laravel version are you using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.6.17

Comment: You need to add .htaccess file, this is something new laravel 5.6, till you dont add it, you will get this error

Comment: I have the file.

Comment: You have to set some rules for the file too, i dont have a project configured at my end, otherwise i would link it to you

Comment: have you tried to use a different port with this, say: `php artisan serve --port=8888`

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin I don't see how that fixes the problem. The laravel development server works fine. It is when I try to run it through apache it fails.

Comment: Well, since you want to serve through Apache, I have only experienced making a Virtual configuration for laravel project by pointing Apache to serve the website from `your project/public` directory. Have you tried that? In this case, you don't need to use `php artisan serve`

Comment: Either I am miss reading or you are suggesting what I tried and posted in my question. Fixed anyway I think.

Comment: Is it bad that I had to do chmod 777 for every file in laravel? Actually could not get it working with anything less.

Comment: Yes, 775 is too much to give every file. 775 is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to add:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

to the end of my httpd.conf file

[edit]

Also had to give permission to some files for some reason. (log files).